# Get person name from chatting apps - Android

Tags: android, chat

Currently I'm working on a project where I need to know with who the user is chatting with, in any given time, in chatting apps like Whatsapp, Facebook messenger, Skype, line and other chatting apps.

Could that be done? Is there any API that I can work with to know this information?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not a way to do this. There is no standardized interface for accessing this sort of information. It would be a privacy and security concern if there was.

Specific apps may individually decide to expose a Content-Provider or other means to share this data, but that would be up to the choice of each app, and each would be implemented in it's own way. As far as I am aware, none of the three examples listed do this.